# What are the ups and downs of CentOS and Ubuntu Server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, dedicated-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CentOS vs. Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/53954/centos-vs-ubuntu)

I'm setting up a new dedicated server, and, though I'm mainly familiar with Ubuntu, I'm thinking of trying other systems. I've played a little with other distributions, but mainly stayed away. I don't know if it is either me being spoiled by apt or laziness to learn new tools for the operating system, but do you think it is worth it to use CentOS over Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CentOS vs. Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/53954/centos-vs-ubuntu) for a similar discussion.

It comes down to what you like more, if you are used to using Ubuntu switching to CentOS or another red hat based distro wont really make any noticeable improvement.

I've worked with Ubuntu/Debian systems at work and Fedora/CentOS systems at school and my totally biased and jaded opinion is that the latter too are horrible.  I've always found that apt-get was much better than yum for example.

There are a lot of things that while making no real difference can be annoying, like typing /etc/apach, pressing tab and nothing happening because its /etc/httpd instead. This may not seem like a lot but it can get irritating quickly if you are used to certain things.

All that being said however all of that is just my opinion, if you have the free time give it a try, you may end up liking it a lot more.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying a bunch of different OSes, and pretty much I'm choosing between a redhat based distro, hence CentOS, or what I know, which is Ubuntu/Debian. I'm moving towards CentOS mainly because I'm seeing a few pieces of software made just for RH-based distros, and I'm thinking to use this as a chance to learn a new distro.